# How to pass javaScript variable value in asp-route-id prefix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I've an anchor element with the attribute of `asp-controller` and 
`asp-action`. I've a javaScript variable, named **g_id** that will call the **getIdFromUrl function**. This function will retrieve the id appended at the end of the url.

```
/User/Account/5
```

For example, this function will retrieve the value of **5** from the URL. I want to assign this value to the asp-route-id. However, I am unable to do so.

```
<a asp-action="ActivityPrice" asp-controller="Activity" asp-route-id = "g_id" class="btn btn-primary" >
Add Activity Price
```

```
var g_id = getIdFromURL();

function getIdFromURL() {
    var urlArray = window.location.href.split('/');
    var id = urlArray[urlArray.length - 1];
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Think you are looking for setAttribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: Why are you "unable to do so"? What happens when executing the given code? What do you mean by that variable calling a function?

Comment: @NicoHaase Hi Nico, basically I am trying to use g_id as the value for asp-route-id

Comment: And what is not working? Do you want to write the result of `getIdFromURL` into the attribute `asp-route-id`?

Comment: Yes @NicoHaase I am trying to do that. I am very sorry if my explanation is unclear

Comment: So, what have you tried to achieve this? There should be tons of tutorials to do this.....

Comment: Just a note - `Asp.Net` will render `asp-` tag helpers before giving the HTML code to the browser. There shouldn't be any `asp-` tags in the HTML you view in the browser. `asp-action`, `asp-controller`, and `asp-route-` will all compile into a single `href` tag for an anchor element. Rather than looking to change the `asp-route-id` tag, look to change the `href` tag.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a').attr('action', '/Activity/ActivityPrice/' + g_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Javascript tag yo can define the below function

```
function setRouteParameter() {
    var newhref=$("#addActivityPrice").attr('href') + '/' + g_id ;     
    $("#addActivityPrice").attr("href", newhref);        
}
```

and call it onclick of your anchor element

```
<a id="addActivityPrice" asp-action="ActivityPrice" asp-controller="Activity" asp-route-id = "g_id" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="setRouteParameter()">
Add Activity Price
```

Answer (score 0):

`asp-route-id` is translated to formaction. My solution is

```
var formActionAttr = $("#myBtn").get(0).getAttribute('formaction');
        formActionAttr = formActionAttr.replace("&", "&idLeft=" + "myValue" + "&idRight=" + "myValue" + "&");
        $("#confirmBtn").get(0).setAttribute('formaction', formActionAttr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

`$('a').attr('asp-route-id', g_id);`

Comment: This will add an attribute named 'asp-route-id' but will not change the link href. This is explained in the question comments